vue.js and laravel scorm integration
we're trying to implement Articulate SCORM files on our platform.
Our environment consists of Laravel for the API and vue.js for the front end.
We managed to store the file correctly in the database and in the file system.
We can now retrieve a URL to the index .html file in our front-end.
We then tried to use the pipwerks library to retrieve the information from the scorm, but were unable to do so.
We can't connect to the scorm API. Does anyone have any ideas or tutorials on how to implement our project (or part of it)?
Thanks in advance!
we've tried several ways of using
SCORM.init(); 

but the result is always the same:
connection.initialize called. index.js:883
SCORM.API.find: Error finding API.
Find attempts: 0.
Find attempt limit: 500 index.js:883
API.get failed: Can't find the API! index.js:883
SCORM.connection.initialize failed: API is null.


SO won't let me mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286132/the-content-was-unable-to-locate-the-scorm-api-adapter because it doesn't have an accepted answer, but essentially it is the same.

The pipwerks wrapper is a SCORM API wrapper library that enables SCORM content to communicate with the SCORM RTE provided by a SCORM player. It sounds like you are attempting to play Articulate courses, if that is the case then you will need to implement the SCORM RTE for the content to talk to, IOW, you need to implement (or integrate with) a SCORM player. Learn more about the SCORM RTE here: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/ see https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/ for an Overview. If you are interested in integrating rather than building a SCORM player I'd suggest looking at https://rusticisoftware.com/solutions/lmss/#delivery (disclosure: I work for Rustici Software).

@antoine: pipwerks wrapper === course/client side. Articulate uses its own code (provided by Rustici software I believe) on the client side. As Brian describes, you need the LMS/server side, which provides the API that the client side connects to. The pipwerks SCORM API wrapper is not going to help you in your scenario.
